# Different record fetch from the same dbs

Tags: javascript, mysql, heroku, cleardb

i have two node.js application one is hosted on Heroku and the other is hosted locally, both are connected to the same database hosted on heroku clearDB extension. however , im getting different records when i fetch some data . but not competently, when i add a new record it's retrieved correctly by both application.

code on both environments(local,heroku server):

```
function getAppointments(user,callback){
 var sql = 'SELECT * FROM appointments_3sd3df WHERE clinic_id = ?';
 pool.query(sql,[user.clinic_id], function(error, results){
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results);
  callback(results);
 });
}
```

[left data on Heroku server right is local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGh2V.png)

Comment: Could you, please show how you fetch the data and what kind of responses you get?

Comment: @ArtemK i added the code thx

Comment: Could you, please  `SELECT * FROM appointments_3sd3df WHERE clinic_id = ? ORDER BY appointment_time` to easily see the differences in returned data? (or whatever your `appointment_time` column is called).